# Please what font is this?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[image: 3d font - help needed in identifying it]

Hi All,

I need to recreate a design for a client and need to know what font this is. This is originally from on online ad running in Nigeria.

I have tried using whatthefont.com, but still can not find it.

Answer (score 4):

The white italic texts: Serapina Italic

[image]

The yellow and red: I guess the same as the white italic

Green with white edges: No idea. It can be custom drawing which is extruded.As well it can be of some comics font with thick white stroke and extruded. Illustrator's 3D creates the extrusion and perspective easily.